# Removing PHP Extension in sub directory

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use the following rewrite rule to remove the .php extension from my page urls:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This works great in the root directory of my website as well as in the admin subdirectory with the exception of /admin/index.php

If I try to go to /admin or /admin/  without specifying the filename I get this error:

`The requested URL /admin/.php was not found on this server.`

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I try to go to /admin or /admin/ without specifying the filename I get this error:

Because `/admin/` is a *directory* and your directive only checks that the request does not map to *file*. So the conditions are satisfied and it redirects from `/admin/` to `/admin/.php` (as per your `RewriteRule`).

You need to add another condition that checks that the request does not map to a directory. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

NB: You don't need to backslash escape a literal dot when used inside a character class as it carries no special meaning here. Also, the `NC` flag is superfluous since the regex naturally matches `a-z` and `A-Z` anyway.